# Combining data and splitting complex structured data

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

[image]

In the image you see ASIN (product codes) in the first column, dates along the first row and product ranks (morning and evening ranks - split by a comma) in all other cells. The product rank cells can be fully blank also.

How can I write a formula to obtain four columns (as below) that summarises all this data:

ASIN,Date,Time(MorningOrEvening),Rank

As a first step, I tried to use UNIQUE on ASIN then REPT on this with a COUNTA to repeat each ASIN by the count of dates but this didn't work. I guess I need to use ARRAYFORMULA? Once I had a list of  ASIN-Date combinations I was thinking to then use INDEX MATCH and SPLIT to reference each ASIN-Date combination to the right ranks.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Always much easier if you supply a table of example data or a link to a sheet containing the example data... but assuming that the cross-table you've shown in the picture is found starting at A1 in a tab and that tab is named 'data', you can use the following formula in another tab to give you a flat table with the required layout:

```
=arrayformula(let(
source,Overview!A1:ZZZ,
asin_count,counta(choosecols(source,1))-1,
date_count,counta(chooserows(source,1))-1,
flat1,split(tocol(offset(source,1,0,asin_count,1)&"|"&offset(source,0,1,1,date_count)&"|"&offset(source,1,1,asin_count,date_count)),"|"),
asin,choosecols(flat1,1),
date,choosecols(flat1,2),
splitranks,split(choosecols(flat1,3),","),
flat2,split(tocol({asin&"|"&text(date,"dd/mm/yyyy")&"|"&{"Morning","Evening"}&"|"&splitranks}),"|"),
header,{"ASIN","Date","Time","Rank"},
query({header;flat2},"where Col1<>'#VALUE!'",1)))
```

I'm employing string manipulation (&, SPLIT and TOCOL) to flatten the table; this has to happen in a couple of stages because your rank cells contain two different datasets. There are other ways of doing this but I find string manipulation easier to understand. The QUERY at the backend removes the '#VALUE!' errors in the ASIN column where the input data contained blank rank cells. Note that your input data also contains a row for 4/10/23 with only one rank rather than two - this formula will interpret that as being the 'morning' rank so there will be rows containing no rank for the evening also present.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This mostly works but I have some errors in the first column. See Google Sheet below:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1OBcCErPTy2N8Fd_zCOCEGscWY8asn9yc6azQVkzPbPU/edit?usp=sharing

I think it's because there are blank "rank" cells in the Overview sheet that cause this error?

Comment: I have updated the formula to handle the errors.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need to convert the wide data to the long data to get the four columns of attributes you need. If you're using R or Python, use the spread function (R) to solve the problem. If you want to implement this inside Excel, follow my steps below.
Step1: Save the prepared wide table Data in an excel file, and then create a new excel file, press data --> Get Data --> From File --> Import data From Workbook.

Step2: Choose the first column (your Unique ASIN), the click Transform --> Unpivot Columns --> Unpivot Other Columns, to transform column names (in this case the dates) to a column called "Time"

Step3：Use commas to separate morning and evening data. (This is easy to do in Excel.)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).